# Objective C create static library with debug option set-able in launch arguments

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, static-libraries

Apple library produces extra debug info when compiled with corresponding debug options. 
e.g. for sqlite debug info compile with `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug` to  `1` in the Arguments list.

How can we give similar options for our clients when creating a static lib?

I used a DEBUG preprocessor var, but want something more elegant than below,

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DLog(...) /* */
#endif
```

for the above, I have to compile my static lib with DEBUG. But I would like to give my user to set the debug as Apple does.

Question is, how the 'arguments passed on launch' is exposed in the code.

Comment: "something more elegant" is very vague - what specific problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: for the above, I have to compile my static lib with DEBUG or not. But I would like to give my user to set the debug as Apple does.

Comment: OK - maybe you could add that requirement to the question, to give people a better idea of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What is the compile command used currently for your static library?

Comment: that i said at first in sqlite example.

Answer (score 1):

To allow runtime control of the debugging options then you need to allow the user to set a debug option, so provide a function to do that:

YourLibrary.h:

```
extern void MyLib_SetDebug(BOOL debug);
```

YourLibrary.m

```
static BOOL _debug = NO;

void MyLib_SetDebug(BOOL debug)
{
    _debug = debug;
}
```

and create a log function that checks this debug flag and avoids writing if not set:

```
void DLog(NSString *format, ...)
{
    if (!_debug)
        return;
   va_list va;
   va_start(va, format);
   NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:va];
   va_end(va);
   NSLog(@"%@", message);
}
```

and then delete that `DLog` macro you are using.  You can then compile in Release mode and get debugging behaviour as required at runtime.